# How to set max time limit in jQuery timepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I am using jQuery's timepicker plugin and I set the start time, and I need to set max time limit for timepicker.
So I kept max time using `endTime` attribute, but this seems to be not working out for me.

Expected output:

1)Start time should be morning 7:00 AM and endtime 4:00 PM.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 60,
    startTime: '7:00 am',
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true,
    endTime: '4:00 pm',

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `min` and `max` instead of `startTime` and `endTime`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 60,
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true,
    min: '7:00 am',
    max: '4:00 pm'
});
</script>
```

Comment: showing error timepicker is not function even kept jquery in proper order

Answer (score 0):

use `minTime` and `maxTime`

```js
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 60,
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true,
    minTime: '7:00am',
    maxTime: '4:00pm',
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">

<input type="text" class="timepicker">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```